# Unity InputSystem Issues: Cannot edit bindings unless attached to a composite

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input

I'm probably being stupid (would not be the first time), but I for some reason cannot edit bindings in the InputSystems menu unless they are part of a composite control.

I have no idea why and would like some help on solving the issue on my project.

The following images have the menu on a composite bind and later on a singular bind.

[image: Composite Binding]

[image: Singular Binding]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the issue, this is actually caused by InputSystems not recognizing the external application VJoy which is commonly used for emulation. I would recommend that unity fixes this, but outside of that my only solution is to completely uninstall the program and its drivers. Any unrecognized device will completely disable all binding edits in the editor.